# Express in base π the circumference of a circle of radius 1.

Tags: geometry, circles, pi

Express in base π the circumference of a circle of radius 1.
Not sure how to approach this problem. Can you help?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_base_of_numeration Can you answer the question based on this definition?

Answer (score 2):

For example, the number $42$ in base ten means $$4\cdot\text{ten}^1+2\cdot\text{ten}^0$$

That radius $1$ is a "$1$" in base ten (I assume). Meaning, it's $1\cdot\text{ten}^0$. So you know that the circumference is $2\pi$. That is, it equals $$2\cdot\text{pi}^1+0\cdot\text{pi}^0$$
Can you now see how to write that in "base pi"?

Comment: Is $\color{red}{42}$ a random choice or because it is the answer to .... ?

Comment: but how to convert 2π in base π?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici a little bit of both

Comment: @sunil Follow the example with 42 first. How does $4\cdot\text{ten}^1+2\cdot\text{ten}^0$ become "42"? Then apply that same process to $2\cdot\text{pi}^1+0\cdot\text{pi}^0$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 20 (in base $\pi$)

Allowed digits if the radix is $\pi$ are 1, 2, 3, and ${\pi}_{10}$ ($\pi$ in base 10) is $10_{\pi}$ (in base $\pi$).

So the Circumference is (base 10) = 2 * $\pi$ = 2$\pi$.

So the Circumference is (base $\pi$) = $2_{\pi} \times 10_{\pi} = 20_{\pi}$.